# setWallpaper(bitmap) doesn't set fullscreen wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

so I am trying to create an app where the user can press a button to take an image with the phone's camera, and then press another button to set that image as the phone's wallpaper.

I started the camera intent with this: (this is in an onClick method)

```
Intent i;

i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraResults);
```

Then I implemented this method to receive the image from the camera:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Then, in the onClick method of the button that sets the wallpaper as the bmp, i used:

```
getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
```

When I run this app, everything seems to work perfectly! The picture is taken, I set an imageView as the picture, and then when i press the button to set the image as my wallpaper, my wallpaper changes.

**HOWEVER, the problem is that the image from the camera doesn't correctly set as the wallpaper. For some reason, the picture decreases in size, so that only the middle of the wallpaper is that image. Most of the screen is black. The image was scaled down for some reason. I want the picture to be full screen, but right now, it is minimized, and the background is black.**

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I am following a tutorial video, and the person in the tutorial gets it working perfectly (the image is set as the wallpaper full screen).

I appreciate all help, thank you very much!

Anyone else know how I can scale it so that I set the wallpaper fullscreen?

Comment: most cameras, or at least my htc droid incredible have a 8mp camera on the back when you take the photo the amount of memory that it takes to view one full size photo is huge, if you don't scale you can run out of memory places. You need to pre scale it properly so the os doesnt do it for you already

Comment: @L7ColWinters Yes, my phone I am testing on is a galaxy s2, so it does have an 8mp gamera. 

Ok, so I kinda understand what you are saying. The full screen pic would take too much memory, so it is using a small one which contains less data. So how do I solve this problem programmatically? What is the code needed to scale my bitmap down? Thanks for the response btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap that you are extracting is a thumbnail of your image. 
Try 
[this Android official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) on using native camera app and image scaling.